# Facebook Login on Parse

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

Thanks for your time.

I've got the Facebook login tutorial working with all the keys both to Parse and Facebook.  However I don't get any output from it.  When I log in with a valid account and using correct keys for both API's I am dropped back to the "Log In to Facebook" screen so my question though simple as it may be is just whether or not that is the normal intended behavior of the tutorial here: https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-android and that I shouldn't be expecting it to show me my account data or even tell me that login was successful?

If it is I'll keep going assuming all my calls will work, if not could you suggest some steps to take to get the rest of it working?

Comment: No it is not normal..If the user is logged in to FB successfully you will get a log msg "User logged in through Facebook!" and showUserDetailsActivity is called.. And the user details are displayed. I believe you are not even asked for permissions when you try to log in.! Are you getting access token first up

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I don't know how to check for an access token but nothing looks off in logcat?

Comment: Update: It looks like my access token is wrong, but I copied the App ID directly from my Facebook App test page.  What can I do?

Comment: Session session = ParseFacebookUtils.getSession()
Log.i(TAG, "Access Token" + session.getAccessToken());

Try this and see if you can get the access token